# Connection reset for multi-part file upload using requests python library

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to write a script to do a bunch of rest calls. I have two file upload calls
a) File size is 1.6M
b) File size is 113M

The second call fails with a message "Connection reset by peer". The following is a snippet of the file upload code

```
import requests  


auth_headers={'X-MW-Token':auth_token,'Connection':'keep-alive','Content-Type':'multipart/form-data'}
upload_url='https://foo.bar.com/uw/upload/s_file_upload'
files = {'file':('m.support',open('m.support','rb'),'application/octet-stream')}
r = requests.post(upload_url,files=files,headers=auth_headers,verify=False)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Is there something explicit to be done if the file size is huge?