# Python requests: Connection reset by peer for multi-part file POST

Tags: python, python-requests

Same problem as this unanswered question: [Connection reset for multi-part file upload using requests python library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567003/connection-reset-for-multi-part-file-upload-using-requests-python-library)

I'm POSTing a multipart form request to a locally running server and it works fine for small files, but if I try to send a larger file (~20MB) then I get the following error:

```
File "~/.virtualenvs/sound-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
File "~/.virtualenvs/sound-api/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1106, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1151, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1102, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 936, in _send_output
    self.send(message_body)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 905, in send
    self.sock.sendall(datablock)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Here is the code making the request:

```
files = {
    'file': my_file
}
data = {
    'parameter': 'some data'
}
session = requests.Session()
result = self.session.post(
    url,
    files=files,
    data=data
)
return result
```

I'm running Python 3.5.2 with requests 2.18.4 in a virtualenv.
Am I missing some setting or library to allow me to send larger files?

Comment: Is the locally running server behind an apache/nginx proxy? and if so has the max upload size value been set? I believe it defaults to ~2MB

Comment: It's a spring boot application running tomcat.
There is a max file size set, but an Exception is thrown and an appropriate error response is returned.

Using postman I can successfully make a request with a file over the max file size and get the correct error response, yet the same request using requests in python results in the above error.

Comment: @arcticfeather: I'm sure that POSTman will also have the connect closed early; it is just then choosing to give you a formatted error message. What happens when you increase the limit, can you then post correctly?

Comment: @martijn-pieters
I increased the max size and the request went through.

But I don't understand why the connection is closed early when using requests, while both postman and curl get a response from the server.  (It's a response that I set, so it's not being generated by Postman etc.)